# How do you check if a Loader is still loading or running?

Tags: android, loader

How do you do this normally? What I want is to check the "state" of the loader: if it is running, or it has stopped. There are not enough questions on this issue which I think it fairly important

Answer (score 0):

`getLoaderManager().getLoader(id).isStarted()` is about as far as I can see using the available APIs. If you need something more refined, you'll probably have to subclass whichever `Loader` you are using now to add some extra state information, then cast to that after calling `getLoader(id)`.

Comment: I can't seem to cast. getLoader(id) from the loader manager seems to have generic return type. How do you go around this?

Comment: @JohnErnestGuadalupe I don't see why you can't just do `MyLoader loader = loaderManager.getLoader(id)`. This shouldn't give you an error at compile time; if it is, please say what the error it gives.